# api-platform: How to limit collection dataset?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com

Reading the api-platform documentation, I couldn't find what is the best / recommended way to limit the queryset of a collection endpoint:
Examples of this would be:

- I only want to return objects that belongs to the logged in user
- Only want to return objects with property `aproved==true`

Comment: If you want these filters work the same for each request see [the docs on Extensions](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extensions/#custom-doctrine-orm-extension)

Answer (score 0):

> I only want to return objects that belongs to the logged in user

Consider using [sub resources](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#subresources). So your API remains stateless. You can retrieve your objects like this `/users/{user_id}/objects`.

> Only want to return objects with property aproved==true

There is a built in filter for this: [Boolean filter](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#boolean-filter).